# Can you help me fix my list menu bar in chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, menu, navigation

I have a menu bar that I have created using the li tag and css in order to make it horizontal. However, when  I open it up in Chrome it won't work and is not there at all.

However, when I use IE it is fine.

My code is below:

any help will be very appreciated:

```css
#Navigation {
  margin-left:350px;
  padding-left:0px;
  height:10px;
  width:890px;
  font-family:Helvetica;
  font-size:16px;
}

li {
  list-style-type:none; 
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  width:210px;
}
```

- Home
- About Us
- Our Stores
- Contact Us

Comment: use `li { display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `li` elements percent width like 20% and set `margin: 0 auto` to align to the center of your page:

```css
#Navigation {
    /*margin-left:350px;*/
    padding-left:0px;
    height:10px;
    width:890px;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-size:16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Our Stores</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help, but will this allow the menu bar to appear on chrome? The width is fine because if the nature of the website I am making.

Comment: How is the width fine? A `li` has 230px width x 4 = 920 and your cont has 890 px. Simple math.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I now understand your point. However, It has still not shown up on chrome. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hey dude, Thanks for your help, It was to do with the picture that I had placed above the menu. After I had rid of it, the list had worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For one, you need to clear your floated elements. You can set `overflow: hidden` on the `ul` or use a clearfix. The real issue here is that on top of your fixed width `li`'s being `210px` you have added `10px` of padding to all of them which makes the total width `920px`, bigger than the `890px` width of the parent `#Navigation`. Use `box-sizing: border-box` to force the padding inward and to not effect the width of the element:

```
ul{
  overflow: hidden;
}

li{
  list-style-type:none; 
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  width:210px;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e8oz9faz/2/)